# como puedo cambiar el valor de un registro de mi array

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un array y me gustaría cambiar un registro 'active' que tengo en 1 por defecto, y pasarlo a 0, con este código que tengo ahora mismo consigo cambiar todos los registros  de 'active' y solo quiero que me cambien los tres que muestro, haciendo array_slice. esto quiero hacerlo para que después de 1 hora me muestre los 3 siguientes por el momento intento conseguir lo de cambiar los registros de 'active' para despues pasado una 1hora decirle que muestre los 3 siguientes que todavía no se como se hace pero bueno pasito a pasito.

```
$Standoutproduct_list[] = $val;

$Standoutproduct_list = array_slice ($Standoutproduct_list, 0,3);  
      
Standoutproduct::where('active', '0')->update(['active' => 1]);
      

$data=$Standoutproduct_list;
```

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta es poco concisa. Para cambiar el valor de alguna key dentro de un array, solo bastaría con hacer algo como esto: `$array['key'] = 0`. Por lo tanto no sé muy bien qué tratas de hacer. Te recomiendo modifiques la pregunta para que podamos entenderte mejor.

Comment: Hola gracias y perdona estoy un poco perdida de como se hace , tengo dos tablas una con los productos y otra que relaciono con los productos mediante product_id esta segunda tabla tiene un campo con valor  1 llamado active cuando pasa el array que recojo los 8 productos quiero poner ese campo a 0 de los 8 productos que me muestra el array.

Comment: Aún no logro entenderte muy bien. Si es algo que está relacionado entre tus tablas y tienes tus relaciones correctamente creadas, haciendo uso de lo que dice la documentación en laravel funcionaría. Por eso, edita la pregunta y trata de ser más claro, por favor.

Comment: Hola gaidyjg ya he modificado la pregunta, ahora he conseguido cambiar los registros pero me cambia todos y solo quiero cambiar los tres que se mostraran.